# fast_executemany underlying SQL Operation

Tags: python, sql-server

I'm investigating how the fast_executemany flag in Python changes the behaviour and performance compared to a regular executemany(). For regular I've noted the SQL operation is essentially

```
sp_exec "whatever SQL"
```

performed for each row in the list passed to executemany()

Does anyone know the difference in the SQL command when the fast flag is enabled? From what I've seen it performs the same commands but puts them together in one statement and runs once, rather than running individually?